# Ruby forwarding to a object returned by accessor method

Tags: ruby

I have a class with roughly the following structure:

```
class X
  def initialize
    @container = Container.new
    ....
  end
  def store
    @container.get_store
  end
  def f
    store.f
  end
  def g
    store.g
  end
  def h
    store.h
  end
  ....
end
```

As can be seen, I have a couple of methods, which simply "forward" to *store*, only that *store* is not an instance variable, but the result of a parameterless method. Is there a compact way to implement this forwarding? If `store` would always return the identical object, I could do something like this:

```
class X
  extend Forwardable
  def initialize
    container = Container.new
    @store = container.the_store
  end
  def_delegator :@store, .f, :g, :h
end
```

but I can't rely on this; `@container.the_store` may change during the lifetime of the instance. One alternative I considered is something like

```
class X
  [:f,:g,:h].each do |meth_sym|
    define_method(meth_sym) do |*args|
      store.public_send(meth_sym, *args)
    end
  end
  def store
    @container.get_store
  end
end
```

but this looks clumsy. Can anymody suggest a different solution for my problem?

Comment: `def_delegator :store, :f` should work, i.e. without `@`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the docs for [`Forwardable#def_instance_delegator`](https://docs.ruby-lang.org/en/3.0/Forwardable.html#method-i-def_instance_delegator):

> `accessor` should be a method name, instance variable name, or constant name.

Examples: (both symbols and strings work and `.` is equivalent to `::`)

```
def_delegator :@store, :f     # delegates f to instance variable @store
def_delegator :store, :f      # delegates f to instance method store
def_delegator 'X.store', :f   # delegates f to class method store
def_delegator 'X::Store', :f  # delegates f to constant X::Store
```

Since you have an instance method, you want `:store` (without `@`)

Comment: I see that the docs have improved considerably. We are using Ruby 1.9 and the docs for it don't provide this detail, although the implementation seems to support it already.

Comment: @user1934428 oh indeed, that specific sentence was added later.